# BMI calculation

Tags: c++, beginner

I'm very new to C++ and would like you all to review the source code I wrote for a program that calculates the user's BMI and loops the program back to the start if the user needs to do additional calculations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

float bmiNumber(float pounds, float inches) //BMI calculation
{
  return ((pounds/inches)*703);
  }

void chart(int mF)
{
     if(mF==2) {
 cout<<"\nHere is some info you might find useful...\n"
     <<"At the same BMI, women tend to have more body fat than men."<<endl
     <<"From cdc.gov\n"<<endl;
     }
}
void history()
{
 cout<<"Version History"<<endl;
 cout<<"\tVersion 1.0.1(05/18/2012)"<<endl
     <<"Optimized source code for better program flow,\nImproved calculation algorithms,\n"
     <<"Introduded looping capabilities for\nmultiple calculations without restarting the program."<<endl;
 cout<<"\tVersion 1.0.0(05/15/2012)"<<endl
     <<"Creation of the program, very rough outline of the basic structure."<<endl;
     system ("pause");
}

int main()
{
int changes;
int m;
m=1;

cout<<"Hello and welcome to the BMI Calculation Tool 1.0.1, or BMICT1.0.1 for short."<<endl;
cout<<"If you would like to see the changes from the previous version(1.0.0)\nplease press 3..."<<endl;
cout<<"If not press any other key.";
 cin>>changes;
 if(changes==3)
 {
               history();
               }
cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;               
cout<<"Why don't you first tell me a little bit about yourself,\nby answering just one simple question."<<endl;
cout<<"Are you a man or a woman?";


while(m==1)
{ 
cout<<"If you are a man, please press 1,\nif you are a woman, please press 2."<<endl;
cout<<"Please make your selection now..."<<endl;
 cin>>m;



 if(m==1)
 {
        cout<<"Our sources have indicated that you are in fact a man,\n" 
            <<"please check to confirm this and continue with the program"<<endl;
 }
 else if(m==2)
 {
     cout<<"Our sources have indicated that you are a woman,\n"
         <<"if this is true please continue with the program"<<endl;
}

  else
  {
      cout<<"You have entered an incorrect key..."<<endl;
      cout<<"The program will now close.\n";

      system ("pause");
      return 0;
}
      chart(m);

  float feet;
  float inch; 
  float totalinches;          
  cout<<"Please enter your height as follows..."<<endl;                 
  cout<<"Number of feet: "<<endl;
  cin>>feet;

  cout<<"\nNumber of inches: "<<endl;
  cin>>inch;

  totalinches=(feet*12)+inch;

 cout<<"Your total height in inches is: "<<totalinches<<endl;  
 float inchSqd;
 float lbs;
 float BMI;
 inchSqd=(totalinches*totalinches);
 cout<<"Please enter your weight in pounds: \n";
 cin>>lbs;
 cout<<"Okay, we will now calculate your BMI\n";            
 BMI=bmiNumber(lbs, inchSqd);                                    
  cout<<endl
  <<"Your Body Mass Index Number is: "<<BMI<<endl;

 cout<<endl<<"Once again your BMI is "<<BMI<<", and here is a chart for review."<<endl;
 cout<<endl
     <<     "\tWeight Status"<<endl
     <<" Below 18.5     Underweight"<<endl
     <<" 18.5 to 24.9   Normal"<<endl
     <<" 25.0 to 29.9   Overweight"<<endl
     <<" 30.0 and Above Obese"<<endl;
 cout<<"If you would like to make another calculation press 1, if not press 2..."<<endl;
 cin>>m;
 }

 cout<<endl<<"Thank you for using the BMICT1.0.1 and have a great day.\n";

system ("pause"); 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- `stdlib.h` doesn’t exist in C++. The correct header is `cstdlib` although most (but not all!) compilers will also find the former.
- `using namespace std` is generally discouraged since it may cause prolific name clashes. Instead, import just the names you need, at small scope (i.e. not at file level but in individual functions).
- Parenthetical: if there is *any* chance that this code may be reused (not likely, since it’s a toy example) use SI units, not Imperial ones, for the calculation. If you want to support Imperial input, convert the units to SI on input, and convert back before output, but use standard units internally. Incidentally, this also makes the calculation easier.
- Your `bmiNumber` calculation is wrong: the function claims that it has `inches` as input. But this is a lie: the input is actually *inches squared*. This is a recipe for bugs.
- What does the `mF` parameter in `chart` exactly do?
- The calculation of `totalinches` might be better off in function which takes whole feet and inches as arguments.
- Extensive text data, such as that printed in `chart` and `history` are probably better off in a separate file.
- The `main` function is crowded.

But more importantly, you are using the C++ stream library as an interactive input library, and that’s not what it was designed for, and doesn’t work well for. Unfortunately, C++ doesn’t ship with an interactive console input library. If you insist on the interactivity, use a library such as [Curses for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/544280/1968).

However, console applications are usually designed to be non-interactive, and controlled by command line arguments or config files.

If this were a *real* program, I’d probably design it to be used as follows:

```
bmi --male --size=6ft2 --weight=160lb
```

Or, to output the history:

```
bmi --history
```

Once again, C++ does’t offer great support for this in its standard library, but once again, there are libraries for that. The default on Unix systems os [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) but for C++ a better library is [Boost.ProgramOptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

**The real secret to C++ is to use libraries for everything but the most trivial tasks.** Bjarne Stroustrup, the inventor of C++, once said that,

> Without a good library, most interesting tasks are hard to do in C++; but given a good library, almost any task can be made easy.

Comment: `<stdlib.h>` certainly *does* exist in C++ (§D.5). It's officially deprecated, but the chances of its ever going further than that are essentially nonexistent.

Comment: the use of stdlib.h is there because I was looking for ways to keep the program open on the compilers website. also I was thinking about including a feature that lets the user input si units if they want to so that is a good idea also I would love to be able to put the history in a separate file/program and be able to call on it from this one though i have no idea where to start on that.

Comment: @Jerry My compiler installation (GCC) actually did *not* have this header, that’s why I wrote this. Turns out, I had accidentally nuked the C part of the installation.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try not to repeat too many of @Konrad Rudolph's points:

- Very important here: *clean up the indentation*.  It's all over the place, making your code hard to read for others.  I cannot even tell which level of indentation you're *trying* to use, but whichever it is, just stick with that one.
- The `703` looks like a magic number that should be a constant (with `const`).  This will allow you to use this value anywhere while its use in this program will be known.
- It doesn't appear that `chart()` is doing anything useful, nor does its name make much sense here, so it could be removed.  Functions shouldn't solely print some hardcoded text, as that is not considered useful work.
- You're mixing `std::endl` and `"\n"`, but you really just need the latter as no flushing is specifically needed.
- Be aware that `system("PAUSE")` is Windows-only, thus is non-portable.  If you want to do a portable pause, do something like `std::cin.get()`.  It does work a bit differently, but it is still better to use here.

Overall, it was still hard to review this due to the indentation, and there's probably more that can be addressed here.  Focus on cleaning this up, and it should look better.